# PHP $_POST status: Request was cancelled

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, netbeans

I want to send information with a form written in HTML5 with a script, that it read if it is send or not. The problems is that it seems the information is not sending to PHP so I think the script don't work because that or script is the problem.

This is the PHP block contacto.php

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--
To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>

<?php
   // $mensaje = $_POST('mensaje');
    $mensaje = filter_input (INPUT_POST, 'mensaje');
  //  $mensaje.= "\n--------------\n";
    $mensaje.= filter_input (INPUT_POST,"\n--------------\n");
  // $mensaje.= "\nDe: ". $_POST['nombre'];
    $mensaje.= "\nDe: ". filter_input (INPUT_POST,"nombre");
  // $mensaje.= "\nE-mail: ". $_POST['email'];
    $mensaje.= "\nE-mail: ". filter_input (INPUT_POST,"email");
    //En la siguiente linea ingresamos nuestra casilla de correo
    $destino= "sora_ryu@hotmail.com";
   // $remitente = $_POST ['email'];
    $remitente = filter_input (INPUT_POST,"email");
   // $asunto = "Mensaje enviado por: ".$_POST['nombre'];
    $asunto = "Mensaje enviado por: ". filter_input (INPUT_POST,"nombre");
    mail ($destino,$asunto,$mensaje, "FROM: $remitente");
    //El mensaje que se mostrara al confirmar el envio
    echo "Mensaje enviado. Gracias por contactarse.";
?>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is de script.js

```
var imported = document.createElement('script');
imported.src = 'js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js'; 
document.head.appendChild(imported);

function cargaSendMail(){ 



    $("#c_enviar").attr("disabled", true); 

    $(".c_error").remove(); 

    var filter=/^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]*@[A-Za-z0-9_]+.[A-Za-z0-9_.]+[A-za-z]$/; 


    var s_email = $('#c_mail').val(); 


    var s_name = $('#c_name').val();      


    var s_msg = $('#c_msg').val();  



    if (filter.test(s_email)){ 


    sendMail = "true"; 


    } else{ 


    $('#c_mail').after("<span class='c_error' id='c_error_mail'>Ingrese e-mail valido.</span>"); 


     //aplicamos color de borde si el se encontro algun error en el envio 


    $('#contactform').css("border-color","#e74c3c");     


    sendMail = "false"; 


    } 


    if (s_name.length === 0 ){ 


    $('#c_name').after( "<span class='c_error' id='c_error_name'>Ingrese su nombre.</span>" ); 


    var sendMail = "false"; 


    } 


    if (s_msg.length === 0 ){ 


    $('#c_msg').after( "<span class='c_error' id='c_error_msg'>Ingrese mensaje.</span>" ); 


    var sendMail = "false"; 


    } 


    if(sendMail === "true"){ 


     var datos = { 


             "nombre" : $('#c_name').val(), 


             "email" : $('#c_mail').val(), 


             "mensaje" : $('#c_msg').val() 


     }; 


     $.ajax({ 


               data:  datos, 


             // hacemos referencia al archivo contacto.php 


             url:   'contacto.php', 


             type:  'post', 


             beforeSend: function () { 


             //aplicamos color de borde si el envio es exitoso 


                    $('#contactform').css("border-color","#25A25A"); 


                     $("#c_enviar").val("Enviando..."); 


             }, 

             success:  function (response) { 

                    $('form')[0].reset();   


                    $("#c_enviar").val("Enviar"); 


                    $("#c_information p").html(response); 


                    $("#c_information").fadeIn('slow'); 


                    $("#c_enviar").removeAttr("disabled"); 

             } 

     }); 

} else{ 

    $("#c_enviar").removeAttr("disabled"); 
} 

}
```

Those are the errors + information on netbeans:

Headers:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8383/Project/contacto.php
Method: POST
Status: Request was cancelled.

Request Headers
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Origin: http://localhost:8383
Referer: http://localhost:8383/MonasterioSiambon/Intenciones.html
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36
X-DevTools-Emulate-Network-Conditions-Client-Id: 0010C211-C2EB-4F23-B335-73EFF1D2CC9A
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

Request data:

```
nombre=Jose+Luis+Guerra+Infante&email=sora_ryu%40hotmail.com&mensaje=sdad
```

Call Stack:

```
k.cors.a.crossDomain.send (public_html/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:14955)
n.extend.ajax (public_html/js/vendor/jquery-2.1.1.min.js:4:10579)
cargaSendMail (public_html/script.js:120:8)
onclick (public_html/Intenciones.html:307:208)
```

I'll appreciate any help, I'm starting with PHP and AJAX. But I think the problem is in jQuery library maybe?

Comment: Unrelated side note: JavaScript has booleans, you don't need to emulate them with strings.

Comment: Further debugging needed, looks like chrome, so please open this URL in your browser `chrome://net-internals/#events`, then perform your AJAX call, then go back to that tab and debug where it cancels at.

Comment: This is the debug process in chrome 99 SOCKET_STREAM 
 109 SOCKET 
 1520 URL_REQUEST http://localhost:8383/MonasterioSiambon/contacto.php
 1522 HTTP_STREAM_JOB http://localhost:8383/
 1523 HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_REQUEST localhost:8383
 1524 IPV6_REACHABILITY_CHECK 
 1525 UDP_SOCKET [2001:4860:4860::8888]:53
 1526 CONNECT_JOB localhost:8383
 1527 HOST_RESOLVER_IMPL_REQUEST localhost:8383
 1528 IPV6_REACHABILITY_CHECK 
 1529 UDP_SOCKET [2001:4860:4860::8888]:53
 1530 SOCKET localhost:8383

Comment: It seems the problem maybe is in UDP socket? How I can fix this? t=2 [st=0] +SOCKET_ALIVE  [dt=0]
            --> source_dependency = 1528 (IPV6_REACHABILITY_CHECK)
t=2 [st=0]   +UDP_CONNECT  [dt=0]
              --> address = "[2001:4860:4860::8888]:53"
t=2 [st=0]   -UDP_CONNECT
              --> net_error = -109 (ERR_ADDRESS_UNREACHABLE)
t=2 [st=0] -SOCKET_ALIVE